# Existence of formulae for sines/cosines of products of angles in terms of sines/cosines of original angles?

Tags: trigonometry, products

There was something that I was getting a little curious about. We know that there are the so-called *compound-angle formulae* for calculating sines and cosines of sums of angles in terms of those of the original angles:

$$\sin (\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\cos (\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta.$$

Now, do there exist any sort of formulae for **products** of angles, that is, for $\sin(\alpha\beta)$ and $\cos(\alpha\beta)$? If so, how can one derive them? (I had a play and tried to get something, and it ended up being rather nasty; only holding for small-ish angles $\beta$ and resulting in some infinite series that may or may not converge to anything well-known.)

Comment: One has good geometric intuition of what it means to add two angles, but I don't know what it would mean to multiply them. For that reason, I wouldn't expect anything all that nice.

Comment: I have a formula for $\sin(\alpha \beta)$ provided $\alpha$ is a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Chebyshev_method).  :-)

Comment: Have you heard of chebyshev polynomials? I also have to say I'm not sure what to do multiplier is not a natural number.